# Optimize angular code for better scalability and good architecture

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, optimization, angular6

I have a below html code. ( I do not intend to use *ngFor )

```
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate1'>Template 1</div>
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate2'>Template 2</div>
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate3'>Template 3</div>
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate4'>Template 4</div>
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate5'>Template 5</div>
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate6'>Template 6</div>
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate7'>Template 7</div>
   <div *ngIf = 'showTemplate8'>Template 8</div>
```

In my TS file, I have as below

```
displayTemplates(){
   if( condition1 ){
    this.showTemplate1 = true;
    this.showTemplate2 = true;
    this.showTemplate3 = true;
    this.showTemplate4 = true;
    this.showTemplate5 = true;
    this.showTemplate6 = true;
    this.showTemplate7 = false;
    this.showTemplate8 = false;
   }
   else if( condition2 ){
    this.showTemplate1 = false;
    this.showTemplate2 = true;
    this.showTemplate3 = true;
    this.showTemplate4 = true;
    this.showTemplate5 = true;
    this.showTemplate6 = true;
    this.showTemplate7 = false;
    this.showTemplate8 = true;
   }
  else if( condition3 ){
    this.showTemplate1 = true;
    this.showTemplate2 = true;
    this.showTemplate3 = true;
    this.showTemplate4 = true;
    this.showTemplate5 = true;
    this.showTemplate6 = true;
    this.showTemplate7 = true;
    this.showTemplate8 = false;
   }
 }
```

As you see in the code, it looks like a bad code. 
Is there any other approach to make this much cleaner and **SCALABLE**.

Comment: Couldn't you use an array of booleans instead?

Answer (score 1):

> Here is some improvement you can make in your code

```
resetToTrue(){
    this.showTemplate1 = true;
    this.showTemplate2 = true;
    this.showTemplate3 = true;
    this.showTemplate4 = true;
    this.showTemplate5 = true;
    this.showTemplate6 = true;
    this.showTemplate7 = true;
    this.showTemplate8 = true;
}

displayTemplates(){
   if(condition1 ){
    this.resetToTrue();
    this.showTemplate7 = false;
    this.showTemplate8 = false;
   }
   else if( condition2 ){
    this.resetToTrue();
    this.showTemplate1 = false;
    this.showTemplate7 = false;
   }
  else if( condition3 ){
    this.resetToTrue();
    this.showTemplate8 = false;
   }
 }
```

> User `this.resetToTrue()` if most of the fields are true else you can create a method `this.resetToFalse()` which sets all values to `false`.